# OS X OpenGL 3.2 Core (Black Screen)

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, graphics-programming, vbo

I want to render a Quad via VAO, IBO and VBO but nothing is drawn. I'm using glDrawRangeElements in OS X OpenGL 3.2 Core context. The screen is completely black without any error. GLFW3 is used to create window and context.

Window opening/Context creation code

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
_mainWindow  = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, monitor, NULL);
if(_mainWindow == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
_mainWindowWidth  = width;
_mainWindowHeight = height;
glfwSetKeyCallback(_mainWindow, _onKeyEvent);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(_mainWindow);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();

_openGLVersion = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

Shader sources (compiled successfully). Custom FragColor is binded.

```
_vertexShaderSource =
            "#version 150 core\n"
            "in vec3 in_Position;\n"
            "in vec3 in_Normal;\n"
            "in vec2 in_TexCoord;\n"
            "uniform mat4 ModelViewProjection;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = ModelViewProjection * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";
_fragmentShaderSource =
            "#version 150 core\n"
            "out vec4 FColor;"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   FColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";
```

Vertices

```
Vertex* vertices = new Vertex[6];

vertices[0].nz = 1.0f;
vertices[1].nz = 1.0f;
vertices[2].nz = 1.0f;
vertices[3].nz = 1.0f;
vertices[4].nz = 1.0f;
vertices[5].nz = 1.0f;

vertices[1].y  = height;
vertices[1].v0 = 1.0f;

vertices[2].x  = width;
vertices[2].y  = height;
vertices[2].u0 = 1.0f;
vertices[2].v0 = 1.0f;

vertices[4].x  = width;
vertices[4].u0 = 1.0f;

vertices[5].x  = width;
vertices[5].y  = height;
vertices[5].u0 = 1.0f;
vertices[5].v0 = 1.0f;

_mesh->setVertices(vertices, 6);
vertices = NULL;

Uint16* indices = new Uint16[6];

indices[0] = 0;
indices[1] = 2;
indices[2] = 3;
indices[3] = 0;
indices[4] = 1;
indices[5] = 3;

_mesh->setIndices(indices);
indices = NULL;
```

Buffer update (checked the data, it seems to be correct)

```
// Update VBO
if(_vertexBufferObjectID == 0)
{
        glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferObjectID);
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferObjectID);

float* data = new float[_vertexCount * sizeof(Vertex) / sizeof(float)];
Uint64 begin = 0;
for(Uint32 i = 0; i < _vertexCount; i++)
{
    begin = i * 8;
    data[begin]     = _vertices[i].x;
    data[begin + 1] = _vertices[i].y;
    data[begin + 2] = _vertices[i].z;
    data[begin + 3] = _vertices[i].nx;
    data[begin + 4] = _vertices[i].ny;
    data[begin + 5] = _vertices[i].nz;
    data[begin + 6] = _vertices[i].u0;
    data[begin + 7] = _vertices[i].v0;
}

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * _vertexCount, &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

delete[] data;
data = NULL;

// Update IBO
if(_indexBufferObjectID == 0)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBufferObjectID);
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferObjectID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Uint16) * _vertexCount, &_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Update VAO
if(_vertexArrayObjectID == 0)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertexArrayObjectID);
}
glBindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObjectID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferObjectID);
// Vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), ((char*)NULL + (0)));
// Normals
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), ((char*)NULL + (12)));
// TexCoords
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), ((char*)NULL + (24)));

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferObjectID);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Rendering code

```
glUseProgram(material->_programID);
GLuint mvp = glGetUniformLocation(material->_programID, "ModelViewProjection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp, 1, false, glm::value_ptr(camera_mvp));

glBindVertexArray(node->_mesh->_vertexArrayObjectID);

// Draw
glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, node->_mesh->_vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Note: camera_mvp is Orthographic

```
0.00333333_0___________0 0 
0__________0.00333333__0 0 
0__________0__________-1 0 
599________599_________0 1
```

Program Linking

```
_programID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(_programID, vertex_shader);
glAttachShader(_programID, fragment_shader);

glLinkProgram(_programID);
glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
glGetProgramiv(_programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &loglen);

if(loglen > 0)
{
    char* log = new char[loglen];

    glGetProgramInfoLog(_programID, loglen, 0, log);
    _lastInfoLog = log;

    delete log;
    log = NULL;
}

if(result == GL_FALSE)
{
    glDeleteProgram(_programID);
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    return false;
}

glUseProgram(_programID);
glBindAttribLocation(_programID, 0, "in_Position");
glBindAttribLocation(_programID, 1, "in_Normal");
glBindAttribLocation(_programID, 2, "in_TexCoord");
glBindFragDataLocation(_programID, 0, "FColor");
glUseProgram(0);

glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
```

Comment: You need to debug the code and ensure that you're properly catching errors. Start from a known working example and move on from there. With the amount of code you've included here, it's clear you haven't gotten very far in narrowing down where the problem might be coming from. You should do so and update your question with more specifics.

Comment: I'm catching ALL errors at the main loop event and as you know I cannot skip any of them just because they are stacked. I've placed a lot of code here just because any OpenGL adept could see anything he needs to write the answer. I really don't have any idea why it doesn't work. I debugged all my code and didn't discovered anything wrong. If I could cout from shaders I've solved the problem but I'm writing like a blind man trying to guess what's wrong. I decided to write here just because I was fighting with my problem for several days.

Comment: Have you tried tools like [gDebugger](http://www.gremedy.com)? You can view VBO data on the graphics card and see any OpenGL errors that come up.

Comment: My OS X version is not supported by gDEBugger :C

Comment: @nmindiedev there's a few things a little suspect at first glance. Did you make sure that the `Vertex` class initialises all the values to  `0.0` like you seem to assume? Also what are those `599` entries in the MVP matrix, I don't think I've seen anything but 0 in those 2 positions of the matrix. Then there's of course the matter of the depth buffer, do you have one, if not, did you make sure to disable depth test, if you do, did you make sure to clear it before drawing again?

Comment: @nmindiedev also, make sure you call `glfwInit()` and after each frame `glfwSwapBuffers()`, since glfw seems to force double buffering and if you always just draw to the back buffer you won't see anything. Also, your indices seem wrong, elements `0` and `3` seem to be the same, so the 2 triangles you are drawing have an area of 0.

All in all, there's too many possible things that could be wrong and you didn't post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), so all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but nothing is changed. Vertices are initialized in constructor, MVP is generated by GLM, GL_DEPTH_TEST was disabled, glfwSwapBuffers is being performed every frame. I have a clue that something is wrong in my shader or in VBO update code but there are so many sample pages that contain different info... That's why I cannot find a solution.

Comment: @nmindiedev still not sure how those indices are correct, they just look wrong, if vertices 0 and 3 are the same then you shouldn't see anything. Like I said the 2 triangles have an area of 0, you can't see them. Also, if you just omit the indices when drawing you still might not see anything if you have backface culling enabled, vtx0 1 2 are clockwise.

Just use a minimal working example and go step by step. You can always just use a simple legacy (compatibility example) and then replace it one by one with a core example. Like I said, the code you posted is not complete, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pasted together a running version [here](http://pastebin.com/3JcuXGrX) (just for demo purposes, I hacked around your existing names and structures)

Like I said, your indices were wrong. How you got your MVP matrix I don't know, but it still looks wrong, maybe you transposed it or printed it out transposed.

Also, the way you used `glBindAttribLocation()` and `glBindFragDataLocation()` is slightly wrong, you need to either call it before linking or link the program again after calling it.

These are your vertecies visualized:

```
1_______2&5
|      /|
|     / |
|    /  |
|   /   |
|  /    |
| /     |
|/______|
0&3     4
```

and you tried to draw 0,2,3 and 0,1,3. As you see that would draw triangles with no area as I explained to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Next time I will be more attentive.